# Rails: Find where an association doesn't exist and declare variable

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm going crazy trying to get this to work. I want to loop through a jointable called TriggersUser to see where the user doesn't have a Trigger record (there are only 3 triggers they can have)

```
if current_user.triggers.any?
    (1..2).each do |n|
     if !current_user.triggers.find(n)
      @next_trigger = Trigger.find(n)
     else
      @next_trigger = Trigger.find(3)
     end
   end
 end
```

I get this error: `Couldn't find Trigger with 'id'=1 [WHERE "triggers_users"."user_id" = ?]`

which is perfect, because the user does not have an associated record with trigger_id 1 in the join table. BUT, I want it to now declare a variable @next_trigger = Trigger.find(1)

What am I missing?

TY!!

Comment: Why don't you use `find_by_id` instead of `find` ?  `find_by_id` returns `nil` when a record does not exist for a given id, so in your case it will be `@next_trigger = nil`

Comment: OMG. yas!  Please add as solution so i can accept. Why does that work instead of find, if find is searching for id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `find_by_id` instead of `find`.

`find_by_id` simply returns `nil` when a record does not exist for a given id.

If you use `find`, then you need to handle the exception. 
You can do this:

```
@next_trigger = Trigger.find(n) rescue nil
```

Comment: And to clarify -- find doesn't return anything, and throws an error? Why 'rescue nil' if it doesn't return nil, as you're saying find_by_id does?

Comment: `rescue` would handle the exception and return `nil` everytime `find` does not find the id.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!